I want to add a custom graph to a specific position on the admin dashboard in Magento 2.4, but it isn't working. How can I fix this?
I want to add a custom graph to a specific position on the admin dashboard in Magento 2.4?
I have tried this but this does not work.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="dashboard">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="device_track_graph" before="dashboard.lastOrders" template="trk_DeviceTrack::dashboard/device_tracking_graph.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>

enter image description here
The following code work but i dont want my custom template on this position:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="device_track_graph" template="trk_DeviceTrack::dashboard/device_tracking_graph.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>

enter image description here

vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/dashboard/salebar.phtml

Before overriding this file, please print a message within it to confirm that it is indeed the correct file.
Block attach to this phtml is:
vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Sales.php

